# Bail conditions - check in with a probation officer?

Tags: united-states, bail

If a person is out on bail, is a possible bail condition for them to check in with a probation officer? Or what is the title of the official individual who makes sure bail conditions are continuing to be met?

Comment: That depends on the jurisdiction, and possibly also on translations for non-english-speaking countries. Can you clarify which country you mean?.

Comment: @o.m. primarily the United States. Thanks for the help!

Comment: In E&W reporting for bail is done at a police station

Comment: it depends on exactly what your bail conditions are. Some people have to report to police daily or weekly, others have to rent and wear an ankle monitor and others have to hand in their passport only. Or hand in all their firearms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is the title of the official individual who makes sure bail conditions are continuing to be met?**

**Pretrial Services Officer** Either at [Federal](https://www.uscourts.gov/services-forms/probation-and-pretrial-services/probation-and-pretrial-officers-and-officer) or  State/[County](https://pretrial.harriscountytx.gov/Pages/default.aspx) level.

In the United States there are several [Types of Bail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bail_in_the_United_States), which vary from jurisdiction, and this one seems relevant to the OP:

> **Pretrial Services** – a defendant is released to the supervision of a pretrial services officer, similar to a probation officer. In most cases defendants have no financial obligation to be supervised. The [Pretrial Services Programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretrial_services_programs) can include phone or **in-person check-ins**, drug testing, court date reminders, and any other condition the judges deems necessary.

*FYI a Probation Officer manages offenders post-conviction who have been sentenced to probation, whereas bail relates to suspects who have not been convicted (or offenders who have been but are awaiting sentencing)*.

Comment: This said, many rural and small town courts have a single job description of "probation officer" who handles pretrial services, probation, and sometimes other tasks as well (rarely parole, however, which is usually a state government function rather than a local government function). The U.S. isn't known for the uniformity of its criminal justice system.